# Why can variable declarations always overwrite function declarations?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, declaration

No matter whether I define the function after the variable

```
var a = 1;
function a() {};
typeof a // number
```

Or if I define the function before the variable

```
function a() {};
var a = 1;
typeof a // number
```

the final `typeof` result is always `number`

I found some explanation about `execution context` in http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/

```
Before executing the function code, create the execution context.
......
Scan the context for variable declarations:
If the variable name already exists in the variable object, do nothing and continue scanning.
```

but this does not seem to work.

So how can I explain it?

Comment: Try `var a = function(){};` and see what `typeof` returns.

Comment: [Javascript parse/evaluation order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742195/javascript-parse-evaluation-order)

Comment: function a(){} will(should) always be hoisted before var in a scope.so the latest type of a is always number. That's why in "modern" javascript it's better to declare named functions as var a=function(){}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's to do with JavaScript's [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting). Try this instead:

```
var a = 1;
var a = function() {};
typeof a // function
```

Answer (score 1):

You're implicitly declaring the variable multiple times by using the function statement 'function a() {};', which as noted by others hoists the variable and behaves unexpectedly due to the order that the browser registers the declarations.

Behind the scenes, this statement instantiates a function object and assigns the result to the variable passed as the function name ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)) but this is done before the explicit var declarations are performed, and so that overrides the implicit declaration.  If you just do the following, it will work more intuitively:

```
var a = 1;
a = function(){};
console.log(typeof a);  // function
```

This is a better option than the multiple var declaration in the other answer from a logical standpoint because (even though you can), it's not a good practice to declare the variable multiple times anyway.

To specifically answer the 'why' for this question: it's so that you can use these kinds of statements to define functions and use them in your explicit declarations, as in

```
var a = someFunction();  
function someFunction(){ return 'someVal'; }
```

If the function statements weren't parsed and hoisted first, this wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, it has to do with the way JavaScript hoisting works. The main issue to notice is that JavaScript will hoist the complete function definition (along with the function body) up to the top, but keeps the variable initialization where it is (only the declaration is hoisted).

So if you write this:

```
var a = 1;
function a () {
}
```

it will be translated to:

```
var a;
function a() {
}
a = 1;
```

and if you write this:

```
function a () {
}
var a = 1;
```

it will be translated to:

```
function a () {
}
var a;
a = 1;
```

So no matter what you do, `a = 1;` will remain at the very bottom.

Please note that the above "translations" should be seen theoretically. JavaScript probably has a way to omit the `var a;` statement if there is already a function declaration with the same name. And there also might be a defined order (functions get hoisted before variables or the other way around). But all of this doesn't affect the outcome of the variable initialization being the only part that is NOT hoisted at all.