# What is the difference between var foo=function() and function foo()

Tags: javascript, function

I have a JavaScript class **Test** that has a private function **foo** that looks like this:

```
function Test(){}
(function()
{
    var foo = function(){
        // do stuff
        console.log('private work');
    }

    this.publicStuff = function(){
        foo();
    }

}).apply(Test);
```

and one that looks like this

```
function Test(){}
(function()
{
    function foo(){
        // do stuff
        console.log('private work');
    }

    this.publicStuff = function(){
        foo();
    }

}).apply(Test);
```

they both work OK and do same stuff and can even coexist like this:

```
function Test(){}
(function()
{
    var foo = function(){
        // do stuff
        console.log('private work VAR');
    }

    function foo(){
        // do stuff
        console.log('private work FUNC');
    }

    this.publicStuff = function(){
        foo();
    }

}).apply(Test);
```

But when they are together, the **var foo = function()** gets executed and the other one not.

What is the difference between the two ways of defining these private functions, what is the best practice and what are the advantages/disadvantages of each aproach

Comment: Do you know about variable hoisting?

Comment: Wrong dupe target. It’s [Why can variable declarations always overwrite function declarations?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21139719/4642212).

Comment: You basically overwrite your own function. function foo gets hoisted, then you overwrite it again with var foo, so only one of the two will work if you give them the same name.

Comment: [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#expr-vs-decl) is an article worth reading

Comment: it seems that I wasn't truly aware of JavaScript variable and function hoisting but now I am. Thanks for all you comments.

Comment: Still I'm confused about what's best practice