# would var declaration (such as var x;) overwrite previous value

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I am learning the hoisting concept in javascript. One piece of code which blocked me is this:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(8);
}

var foo;

console.log(foo);
```

Question 1: 
I typed in this code in chrome console, print out is

```
function foo(){
    console.log(8)
}
```

would the variable declaration overwrite the function declaration? I think the print out should be `undefined`

Question 2:
I typed in the same code in an online editer https://jsbin.com/dezixozewi/edit?js,console, it throws error as 'Identifier 'foo' has already been declared'. so it does not allow duplicate declaration at all.

Could any one help to explain the logic behind? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What version of Chrome are you on? The console output from defining a function is also `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

The reason the function is the value of `foo` is because in this line:

```
var foo;
```

You're just stating `foo` - that's a statement that doesn't do anything.

If you actually set `foo` to something, for example "FooBar":

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(8);
}

var foo = "FooBar";

console.log(foo);
```

It overwrites the function, because as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21139719/10221765), declaring anything with `var` that is a value will result in that value being "hoisted" to the top, and as such being the actual value of the identifier.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

> would the variable declaration overwrite the function declaration?

No. Before any code is executed, the runtime finds all function and variable declarations and initializes the new scope with them. Things vary slightly between evaluating script code and evaluating function scope, but the result is the same:

- Duplicate declarations are ignored.
- Function declaration are evaluated at the end and assigned to their respective name.

In global scope, because `foo` is both a function name as well as a variable declaration, the variable declaration is ignored. And since it doesn't have an initializer, the value of `foo` doesn't change when that line is actually evaluated.

The details can be found in the [language specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-globaldeclarationinstantiation).

---

> Question 2: I typed in the same code in an online editer https://jsbin.com/dezixozewi/edit?js,console, it throws error as 'Identifier 'foo' has already been declared'. so it does not allow duplicate declaration at all.

Unclear how jsbin evaluates the code, but it is valid.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

`var foo;` simply points to the memory location of `foo`. It happens that you've already declared a function there, so that's why the value of `foo` is just still the function.

It's no different than if you did:

```
var x = 2;
var x; // We're not setting a value with `=`, so nothing gets overridden 
x; // 2
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If you declare and assign a variable first, and declare a function with the same name, the name will keep the variable value. There are precedence rules in JS hoisting.

Comment: @Aioros yes and functions are hoisted *before* variables; however a variable assignment before the first call to the function will overwrite the symbol binding.

Comment: @Aioros testing of that in the Chrome 71 console shows otherwise. I did: `var x = 2;` then `function x(){}` and then `x` which gives `ƒ x(){}`

Comment: I think that executing the two statements separately in the console will have a different effect; but Pointy is right about my previous comment, the assignment will be evaluated last.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question! The explanation on memory level helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`var foo;` statement declares `foo` variable and set it's value to undefined **if it already has not a value**. Your `foo` has a value, since the `var foo;` actually doesn't do anything.

If you remove the `foo function` and replace it with a simple variable, you will see the same behaviour.